# Android: разные Activity для разных ориентаций.

Tags: android, java, activity

Здравствуйте!

Может есть уже где-то пример сабжа? Будь то блог, или глава в книге.
Ткните меня, пожалуйста, носом :)

Спасибо!

Comment: создаешь папку с леяутами с именем в конце -land и будет тебе счастье

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ нашёл сам.
Для того чтобы автоматически менять Activity при смене ориентации, нужно создать в папке проекта "res/layout-land" xml-файл с таким же именем, как и при вертикальной ориентации.
Таким образом в папке "res/layout" - портретная ориентация, а в папке "res/layout-land" - ландшафтная.

Comment: сам? а комментарий @Gorets?

Comment: @rasmisha, так может он сам его нашел на странице ответов?))) типа знаешь старый прикол, найдите Х. <- вот он )))

Comment: Увидел коммент уже после того как запостил ответ :)

Comment: @NeoTvidoz - это стандартный способ: работает 1 активити с несколькими лейаутами, но не разные активити - на разные ориентации. Изначальный вопрос был некорректный.

Comment: @Barmaley вот я к тому же. Автор сам сморозил, а костылями называет ответ на поставленный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

А чо тыкать то? Детектируй поворот лейаута, да и запускай в этом месте нужный `Activity`.

Или я чего-то не догоняю?

Comment: Это костыли и индусский подход.

Comment: @NeoTvidoz как вопрос задали, так вам и ответили.

Answer (score 0):

[уроки](http://startandroid.ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom.html)

[вкусняшки android и ios](http://idev.by/category/android/)

[тоже не плохо](http://darkraha.com/rus/mobile/android/android04.php)
[банально но для старта часто само то](http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/adapters.php#baseadapter)

[тоже уроки про бд написано оч подробно](http://webhybrid.ru/prog/android/sqlite.php)
[программирование с нуля ... тоже много чего найдется](http://davidmd.ru/tag/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-android-%D1%81-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8F/) 
[список статей очень вкусно](http://habrahabr.ru/post/111603/)

дерзай

Comment: епт не правильно вопрос прочитал ...

Comment: Ничего страшного :)